# Unzipping .Z file in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find the best way to unzip a .Z file in Perl. Using [IO::Uncompress:Gunzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) and [Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) both show the same behavior. In that neither report failing, and they do produce an output file - though the output file they produce is still a compressed file (which can be unzipped using the Unix `gzip -d <filename>`).

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);
my $status = gunzip 'file.16.Z' => 'file.16' or die "failed: $GunzipError";
```

or

```
use Archive::Extract;
my $ae = Archive::Extract->new(archive => 'file.16.Z');
$ae->extract(to => 'file.16') or die $ae->error;
```

What is the best way to unzip a .Z file in Perl? Is it to just make a system call and use `gzip`?

Comment: Is it possible that the original file was actually compressed twice, once with `gzip` and once with `compress`? What does `file file.16.Z` say?

Answer (score 2):

A `.Z` file would have been created using the obsolescent `compress` utility, not gzip. (`compress` predates gzip by nearly a decade.)

If there is a way to uncompress these in Perl, I'm not aware of it. Use the `uncompress` command.

Comment: `gunzip` (or `gzip -d`) is also able to decompress files created by `compress` (i.e.,. `.Z` files).

Answer (score 2):

`.Z` files are not gzipped. They're Lempel-Ziv coded with `compress`. It's still relatively popular, file format internals (like in GIF) and data storage schemes. Your standard library for working with it is [`zlib`](http://www.zlib.org/) which should ring a bell. I got a little confused and thought `IO::Uncompress::Inflate` should work, but it isn't the right format.

You're also being thrown off with `gunzip` because, as the man page says, recent versions of `gzip` are:

> also capable of decompressing files compressed
>      using compress(1) or bzip2(1).

But that doesn't mean the `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` module would work. 
Your code is mostly right otherwise.

I figured it'd be a simple task to take a normal short text file, compress it with `compress text.txt`, getting `text.txt.Z` and then use the `AnyUncompress` perl module as documented, or the `AnyInflate` modlue. But I actually get the same behavior you describe, so it would appear the format is not supported.

```
perl -MIO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress=anyuncompress,\$AnyUncompressError -e\
'my $z = new IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress "text.txt.Z" '\
'or die "failed $AnyUncompressError";while(<$z>){print};'
```

Comment: Compress is not [deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE), it is [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch). See [wikipedia for compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress). This means IO::Uncompress::Inflate can not be used to decompress .Z files.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks; I really thought it was but it seems that they're both LZ77 based in different ways.